# DOCVARIABLE in ms word Field has disappeared, and yet still appears to be functioning. How can I get it back?

Tags: ms-word, field

First off, sorry if this is really basic, but I've been working with fields in a word document for the past few days and I'm finding them quite counterintuitive. I have a document with over 100 images, and I am sourceing those images using the `INCLUDEPICTURE` field. Inside that field there is a `DOCVARIABLE`which contains the path to the image. I set this up to display all 1000 images. I then copied this word file and made a new one because I had a second set of images to display. SoI  copied and pasted a section of the image name in the field codes and replaced it with a new name, e.g. all "image_a" instances were replaced with "image_b" so instead of seeing "image_a_1.png" and "image_a_2-png", the field codes now show "image_b_1.png" and "image_b_2.png" etc. and this has successfully retrieved the correct images so the document looks good.

However after doing this I have noticed that the codes in the fields has now changed. beforehand at the start the appeared like this:

```
 { INCLUDEPICTURE "{ DOCVARIABLE "var_doc_path" }folderwithpics\\image_a_1.pgn" \d }
```

now however after the copy and paste this is what appears:

```
 { INCLUDEPICTURE "folderwithpics\\image_b_1.pgn" \* MERGEFORMAT \d }
```

The doc variable is no longer displayed. What's weird that is that the correct image is still sourced and displayed in the word document, so it seems that the `docvarible` which is essential for the field to reference the correct path, is still active.

There is a problem though, which is that in a new word document, I need to use `INCLUDEIMAGE` to source all of the 1000 images again into this new document, and they aren't getting displayed. I need to go back and manually enter in the full path for each of the images in order for the new word document to access those image.

I think this must have something to do with the fact that the correct path is no longer displayed. Can anyone help me? I think I need to get the document to display  `{ DOCVARIABLE "var_doc_path" }` in the `INCLUDEPICTURE` field again.

As a side note if anyone has a good guide they can reccommend on working with fields I think that would be a great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you copied the document via Windows or via SaveAs, rather than simply copying & pasting content from one document to another, the new document will not contain the Document Variable. By using the \d switch, Word is referencing a copy of the image stored in the document metadata rather than the one in the filepath it can no longer access via the DOCVARIABLE field.

FWIW, the \* MERGEFORMAT switch does nothing useful in an INCLUDEPICTURE field.

Comment: Thanks! Do you by any chance know a good online tutorial for getting to grips with word fields?

Comment: is the root of the problem due to the use of the \d switch or due to the MERGEFORMAT switch?

Comment: «is the root of the problem due to the use of the \d switch or due to the MERGEFORMAT switch?» No. The problem appears to be that you copied the document content rather than the file. Copying content does not replicate the file's metadata - which is where the the Document Variable resides.

Comment: Regarding tutorials on Word fields, I've written a few: For just about everything you might want to do with dates in Word, check out my **Microsoft Word Date Calculation Tutorial**, at https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38719-microsoft-word-date-calculation-tutorial.html. To see how to do a wide range of calculations in Word, check out my **Microsoft Word Field Maths Tutorial**, at:
https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38720-microsoft-word-field-maths-tutorial.html. Both are also available at http://www.gmayor.com/downloads.htm#Third_party. Do read the documents, introductory material.

Comment: For mailmerges, check out the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** page at:
https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html
. You might also want to checkout my **Microsoft Word Catalogue/Directory Mailmerge Tutorial** at https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/38721-microsoft-word-catalogue-directory-mailmerge-tutorial.html or http://www.gmayor.com/Zips/Catalogue%20Mailmerge.zip
The tutorial covers everything from list creation to the insertion & calculation of values in multi-record tables in letters.